# Random Access Memory Modelling in Verilog

Tags: verilog, ram

Is there a better/alternative way of modelling RAM Memory in Verilog other than declaring it as an array of registers? Most of the sources I referred to have memories coded in the following manner.

```
output reg [WIDTH-1:0] word_out; 
input [WIDTH-1:0] word_in, cpu_addr;
input reset, we, clk;
reg [WIDTH-1:0] chip [0:DEPTH-1];

always @ (posedge clk)
begin
  if (!reset)
    begin
      if (we)
        begin
          chip[word_addr] <= word_in;
          word_out <= word_in;
        end

      else
        word_out <= chip[word_addr];
      end
    end
```

Is there an alternative to this, probably using flipflops or something?

Comment: We call those arrays as "register files".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are aware that there are different types of modelling systems in HDLs: 
1) Behavioral modelling - describing the behaviour of the system like a computer program
2) Structural modelling - interconnecting primitive and complex components by signals
3) Mixed - combining (1) and (2)

If you are more into behavioral - use the array representation. It is a best abstraction for "program-like" paradigm. 
If you like more interconnecting existing components - you can model yourself, download or use a RAM from some standard library, that will be represented as a component with inputs and outputs for you.

Comment: I am supposed to use a RAM from some standard library for this project. Could you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Which tools are you using? What is the target device? The libraries are often supplied by the device vendor, since the device can have so-called "macrocells" implementing the whole RAM unit on the silicon, thus reducing the need of using extra logical resources.

Comment: I am using QuestaSim to write the HDL code. I am not sure about the target device as yet. But for now if we suppose that the target device is a Xilinx FPGA of Spartan6 family, how do I obtain the library files?

Comment: @titan Unfortunately I am not familiar with this tool, but it look like it is more of simulator than a compiler/synthesizer. As for Xilinx, if you obtain a copy of their native tool (Xilinx ISE), it has everything you might need for your device. It has so called "core generator" that is capable of defining and customizing standard cells, existing in the target device.

Comment: I have the Xilinx ISE tool but am not well-versed with it. Could you please help me in locating these library files on this tool?

Comment: Once you have created a project for your device (defined the correct chip in the project settings), you will have the "core generator" tool in the "Tools" menu. It is pretty intuitive to use. You can also use integrated help for the cores available.

Comment: @titatn BTW, if you are using the vendor's compiler/synthesizer, it might be smart enough to map your "array" representation into the actual RAM cell on the device by itself.

Comment: I always do my RAMs like this.  This way things are parametrized, and the synthesizer can figure out how best to implement it in block RAM.  Also, it's more portable between different FPGA families and even different vendors.